# Is a complete code always optimal?

Tags: information-theory, data-compression

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality), Kraft's inequality holds with equality when a code is complete. Huffman encoding produces a complete code that is optimal. Are all complete codes optimal and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

No. If I have three symbols with probabilities A = 0.5, B = 0.25 and C = 0.25 then A=0, B=10, C=11 is complete and optimal. B=0, A=10, C=11 is complete but absolutely *not* optimal.

An optimal code on the other hand *must* be complete, because otherwise you can shorten the encoding of some symbol.